# I have a form. On

Tags: laravel

I have a form. When validation fails i redirect to the same page. "mobilepage1.blade.php"

But all my entries are all gone. I want all my entries to stay. Exept the password.

I redirect my page with `View::make`

```
return View::make('mobilepages.mobilepage1', array('errormessages' => 'errormessages'));
```

I use:

```
$input = Input::all();
```

to get the input.

Answer (score 1):

All input

```
return Redirect::to('mobilepages')->withInput(Input::all());
```

Except password

```
return Redirect::to('mobilepages')->withInput(Input::except('password'));
```

[Old Input](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#old-input)

Answer (score 0):

In your form view, use something like this for the inputs:

```
<?= Form::text('title', (Input::get('title') ?: NULL)); ?>
```

The `(Input::get('title') ?: NULL)` operator will return the previous `title` value if it was set and nothing if it wasn't set.

Answer (score 0):

It should be done using something like this:

```
public formSubmitMethod() // Change formSubmitMethod with appropriate one
{
    // This is the form submit handler
    // Set rules and validate the inputs

    $rules = array(...); // set rules here but there are other ways

    $inputs = Input::except('_token'); // everything but _token
    $validatior = Validator::make($input, $rules);
    if($validatior->fails()) {
        // Validation failed
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validatior);
    }
    else {
        // Success
        // Do whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

In your form, use `Input::old('fieldname')`, something like this:

```
{{ Form::input('username', Input::old('fieldname')) }}
```

That's it, now if you redirect back for invalid user inputs then your form fields will be repopulated with old values. Don't use `old()` method in the password field. You can also access the error message for a field using something like `{{  $errors->first('username') }}`, so if this (`username`) field invalidated then the error message for this field will be printed out.

Also, notice that, to redirect back, I've use `Redirect::back()` not `View::make()`, it's (`make`) not for redirecting but for rendering a view to show it.